# summing all values in each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like:

```
col1 col2 col3 total
3    5    6
7    8    null
...
```

I want the total column to the sum of col1, col2, col3 for each for. So in the case, total should be:

```
col1 col2 col3 total
3    5    6    14
7    8    null 15
...
```

What is the quickest to up the entire total column for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select col1, col2, col3, 
       isnull(col1,0) + isnull(col2,0) + isnull(col3,0) as total
from tableName
```

If you want that column to actually form part of the table, your best bet is to make it a computed column. This stops it going out of sync with the rest of the row, while still allowing you to treat it like any other column in a select statement.

A create table statement that will do this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableName](
    [col1] [int] NULL,
    [col2] [int] NULL,
    [col3] [int] NULL,
    [total]  AS ((isnull([col1],0)+isnull([col2],0))+isnull([col3],0))
)
```

Alternatively, in SSMS just goto your table designer, select the `total` column, and paste the expression `isnull([col1],0)+isnull([col2],0))+isnull([col3],0)` into the box titled `computed column specification > formula`

Finally, if you *really* want to just backfill the total column in the table (Dont! Its a bad bad idea. Your data *will* become out of sync later when somebody updates col1,2 or 3 and forgets to update total) just use an update

```
UPDATE tableName
SET total = isnull([col1],0)+isnull([col2],0))+isnull([col3],0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.Is it possible to create a physical column for this table and put the results from your query in for each row? –

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
SELECT *, 
       (SELECT SUM(C) 
        FROM   (VALUES(col1), 
                      (col2), 
                      (col3)) V(C)) AS [Total] 
FROM   YourTable
```

Comment: Ingenius, not seen this sort of syntax for this problem. Does have an estimated subtree cost 10x higher than my example.... both very efficient though in real terms.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw - Yep. The `VALUES` constructor is 2008+. Would be possible to use `UNION ALL` in 2005 or `UNPIVOT`.

Comment: @Jamiec - TBH: This technique is probably more useful for other aggregates than `SUM`. I would do it your way! (+1)

Comment: @Martin Smith. Thanks for this.  I am wondering can you tell me what the V means in V(C). And if it possible to create a physical column for this table and put the results from your query in for each row?